# Fourier Transform of a Horizontally Scaled Function

Tags: fourier-analysis

For $f(x)$ we have that

$$
\widehat{f}(\xi) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-2 \pi i x \xi} f(x)
$$

Now let $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider

$$
\widehat{f(sx)}(\xi) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-2 \pi i (sx) \xi} f(sx) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-2 \pi i (x) \xi} f(x)*{d \over ds}(1/s) = -{1 \over s^2}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-2 \pi i (x) \xi} f(x) = -{1 \over s^2} \widehat{f}(\xi)
$$

through a change in variable $x \mapsto (1/s)x$.

**Question:** Is this calculation correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $\varphi(x)=sx$, so the question is addressing the relationship between $\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{f\circ\varphi}$. We have
\begin{align*}
\widehat{f\circ\varphi}(\xi)&=\int f\circ\varphi(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx\\
&=\int f(sx)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx\\
&=\int f(sx)e^{-2\pi i(sx)(\xi/s)}\dfrac{d(sx)}{s}\\
&=\dfrac{\text{sgn}(s)}{s}\int f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi/s}dx\\
&=\dfrac{\text{sgn}(s)}{s}\widehat{f}(\xi/s).
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you mean $d(sx)/x$ instead of $d(sx)/s$ (since $s$ is constant)?

Comment: Doesn't $e^{-2 \pi i (sx)( \xi /s)} = e^{-2 \pi i x \xi}$?

Comment: No, I really mean that $d(sx)/s=dx$, actually this is a bad notation, one should write formally by substituting $u=sx$.

Comment: No, the $x$ is still in the $e^{-2\pi i\xi x}=e^{-2\pi i(sx)(\xi/s)}$.

Comment: I'm confused what's going on in line 3. You're changing the variable $x$ in the integral?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is me that made the typo, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said that, it is better to use $u=sx$ to do the job, and then change to $x$ back as the dummy variable.

Comment: Why do we have $\text{sgn}(s)/s = |1/s|$ and not $1/s$ as our final factor in the final two steps of your reasoning?

Comment: $s$ may be negative, when you do the change of variable, the domain of integration swipes the $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

Comment: But if $s < 0$, we will also have that $1/s$ is negative, thus canceling the effect of $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}$ already, right? In any event the [Wikipediage page for integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Proposition) doesn't directly mention domain of integration swiping; but isn't this because the domain of integration will swap if and only if the derivative of the change in variable function is negative (so that the effects cancel out)?

Comment: The wikipedia is not correct, it actually requires $\varphi'>0$, but luckily the examples provided meet this requirement. Right now just think of how do we deal with the basic calculus like $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$. If $s=-1$ and $u=-x$, then $du=-dx$, the integral is $\displaystyle\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f(-u)(-du)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-u)du=-s\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-x)dx$.